# Debugging simple ASP.NET Core 2.1.5 template with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, asp.net-core-2.1

Have been beating on this for a couple days now. Created a simple ASP.NET Core app using template in Visual Studio 2017 Professional with all the latest updates. When I try to debug I get this:

[image]

- I'm running VS as admin
- set the startup project correctly
- cleaned and build solution
- all packages loaded fine
- and I have been using VS for a very long time professionally.

All the "Start" options are grayed out and debug start option has "start" when it should say "IIS Express".

[image]

Tried this with several different canned templates across 3 different development machines. They all have the same problem.
Checked many posts and tried pretty much everything I can think of. I have not uninstalled everything and reinstalled yet but probably soon.

Here is where it gets strange. Loaded the "Community" Version and it works great with the same solution. Still does not in "Professional". Then created a new solution with template on my Mac Visual Studio and it also worked great. 
I have VS Professional and Enterprise loaded on all three of my dev computers with same result. Making me crazy. Trying to make the switch to all the new Microsoft Core frameworks. This is my first post so be gentle;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Debugging simple ASP.NET Core 2.1.5 template with Visual Studio 2017

First, please make sure you do not have Multiple Startup Projects enabled:

[image]

Second, excluded the project from the solution and then build solution without it. Then add that project and build solution and set that project as Start Up project.

Third, if above not help you, try to restart the Visual Studio and PC, and create other project type app to check if still have this issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is single project solution so confirmed startup options(as above) and have done multiple reboots during my investigations. Created several simple template solutions. They debug with the community version but not professional. Thx.

Comment: It seems your professional has some issue, have you try to repair or reinstall the professional Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in answering this but it may help others. The answer was re-install Visual Studio 2017. I got things going on some other Dev boxes I have but last night I had the time to circle back on this problem from the original computer. 
This computer had VS 2013, VS 2015 and VS 2017 installed on it. I uninstalled everything, rebooting a few times in the process and then installed the latest VS 2017. Problem solved!
I really hate when the answer is uninstall and re-install solves the problem, but sometimes that's just the answer. 
Thanks Leo, you were spot on.